# How to move the blinking cursor with the mouse in nano editor?

Tags: nano

I am writing a text file through the terminal using *nano*; everytime I need to select a position of a certain line of my text I can't help but scrolling all the lines moving the blinking cursor using the keyboard arrows; is there a way to avoid this and just use the mouse to directly select where I want the cursor to be?

Comment: Reminder: if I want to use gedit I need to type: ssh -X -l root name@ip

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can start nano with the `-m (--mouse)` option. From `man nano`

```
   -m (--mouse)
          Enable  mouse  support,  if  available  for  your system.  When
          enabled, mouse clicks can be used to place the cursor, set  the
          mark  (with  a double click), and execute shortcuts.  The mouse
          will work in the X Window System, and on the console  when  gpm
          is running.
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! thank you very much!!!

Comment: Ok I just wasted 15 years hitting the arrows to navigate. This the most useful "hidden" feature ever. It should be by default.

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your `~/.nanorc` file

```
set mouse
```

This will cause the mouse to work every time you open nano

(source [The GNU nanorc documentation](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nanorc.5.html))

Answer (score 9):

See [*The GNU nano text editor - Feature Toggles*](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html#Feature-Toggles-1):

> [...] the Meta key (Alt or Cmd, shown as *`M-`*) [...]
>
> [...]
>
> `Mouse Support`
>
> *`M-M`* toggles the `-m` (`--mouse`) command-line option.

<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (always after releasing both) might work, too.

<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> (after each other) might work, too.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand that you want to go to a specific line and a specific character in that line, yes? Without moving the cursor manually through the entire file.

**In nano:**

If you hit Ctrl+_ (that's Control Shift -, on my keyboard), it will prompt you to enter a line and column number.

Comment: That's good to know but in the question i was wandering if i can do what you just said with the mouse

Comment: This works but, dude, it is cumbersome to get the line and column to edit.